# If a process stops, will it automatically close its opened file handles?

Tags: c, winapi

Lets say process opens a file handle, then the process stops. (example if it crashes).
Will the handle opened be automatically closed by the OS?

If they remain opened, is there a way to prove it. If they are automatically closed, is there a way to prove it?

Comment: Which OS? Windows 11?

Comment: of course windows auto close all user mode opened handles. if os not do it - wil be huge handle and other resources leak

Comment: If the program crashes the file output buffers may not be flushed, so you may lose data.

Comment: As you write yourself in your question "closed by the OS?" this is not language specific but os specific.

Comment: The best way to "prove it" will be to "abuse" the fact that Windows will not let you remove an open file, so run a second process that does that after the first one crashes.

Comment: There were operating systems that did not recover resources used by a program that crashed — the original AmigaOS was one such, IIRC, and there were probably other examples in earlier systems before the theory was well understood.  Such systems were vulnerable to running out of resources because of misbehaving software, and could not be regarded as reliable.  Modern o/s clean up after processes — releasing memory and file handles and so on — when the program exits, whether that's under control or not.

Comment: Good idea on the way proving of proving it. Run a process that opens a file then crash on purpose. Then try to delete it. And indeed it can be deleted. So I guess the handles are closed.

Answer (score 0):

After reading  Carlo Arenas suggestion. I made this program to test if they are closed or not.

```
define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    HANDLE file = CreateFileA("test.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    
    if(file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return 1;
    }
    
    printf("Opened the file. Test if you can delete it. then press enter");
    getchar();
    printf("Now will crash. Try to delete the file.\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    
    // Cause crash
    *(int*)0 = 0;
    
    CloseHandle(file);
    
    printf("Success!\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

And indeed the file was created and could be deleted after the crash but not before. So yes, windows does close the handles. Of course you would likely lose anything that is written to the buffer at the moment of the crash (although I haven't test it)

Answer (score 0):

Generally the file handles (as well as other kernel object handles) will be closed when the process quits, but with caveats. One obvious case of the contrary behavior - if the handle was created as inheritable, and the process in question has started a child process with handle inheritance enabled, then the handle will definitely outlive the original process. That's documented behavior, not a quirk.

All that said, one should not confuse handle lifetime with the underlying object lifetime. Specifically files are persistent, so that's not an issue, but for in-memory objects (e. g. mutexes) the object lifetime is a more pertinent question (with a more involved answer) than handle lifetime.

Answer (score -1):

First of all. This is os dependent and not language dependent. So you will have to refer to the specific os you're using.

But all modern operating systems do clean up resources, with the exception of very specialized operating systems. Linux, Windows and MacOS does it.

> If they remain opened, is there a way to prove it.

Depends. In Windows, you are not allowed to delete an open file. So if you cannot delete a file you have opened in a crashed program, it's pretty good evidence.

> If they are automatically closed, is there a way to prove it?

Same there, but opposite. If you can delete the file you opened in the crashed program, then it's closed. In Windows, that is.

Comment: Re "*In Windows, you are not allowed to delete an open file.*", That depends entirely on the parameter you passed when you opened the handle. That is what happens when you pass zero.

Comment: Question being tagged winapi addresses the first paragraph